# Using requestAnimationFrame in a class

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

requestAnimationFrame does not return a regular `this` when I use it in a class.

I've been looking all posts about the subject (tried to encapsulate the `step()` function as an anonymous function into animate...), but I still have the same issue.

```
class Sprite {

  constructor(canvas, imageSrc) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.src = imageSrc;
    this.height = 18;
    this.width = 16;
    this.scale = 4;
    this.scaledWidth = this.scale * this.width;
    this.scaledHeight = this.scale * this.height;
    this.cycleLoop = [0];
    this.currentLoopIndex = 0;

    this.img.onload = () => {
      this.init();
    }
  }

  init() {
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  }

  drawFrame(frameX, frameY, canvasX, canvasY) {
    this.ctx.drawImage(
      this.img,
      frameX * this.width,
      frameY * this.height,
      this.width,
      this.height,
      canvasX,
      canvasY,
      this.scaledWidth,
      this.scaledHeight
    );
  }

  animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.step());
  }

  step() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.ctx);
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    this.drawFrame(this.cycleLoop[this.currentLoopIndex], 0, 0, 0);
    this.currentLoopIndex++;


    if (this.currentLoopIndex >= this.cycleLoop.length) {
      this.currentLoopIndex = 0;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(this.step());
  }
}
```

In `step()`, the first `console.log(this)` shows a Character object with ctx attributes. The second `console.log(this.ctx)` is undefined for some reasons.

So I get a:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearRect' of undefined
    at Character.step (sprite.js:49)
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Es6 class “this” in callback of requestAnimationFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197700/es6-class-this-in-callback-of-requestanimationframe) and also [Use requestAnimationFrame in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908999/use-requestanimationframe-in-a-class)

Comment: Also, you should not include the parentheses when passing a function directly to `requestAnimationFrame`, as that will just call the function immediately instead of passing a reference to it. (`requestAnimationFrame(this.step)`)

Comment: Tried the "ES6 Class "this"" solution. Nothing gets executed it seems.
Tried the `this.step` without parentheses too.

Comment: In the case of that solution you are *not* passing the function directly, but instead using an arrow function, so you do need the parentheses: `requestAnimationFrame(() => this.step())`

Comment: yep, both ain't working though :)

Comment: Are you calling `step()` before the `ctx` has been created? Meaning `step()` is called before the `onload` > `this.init()` > `this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.canvas = canvas;
```

is defined inside the construtor of your Sprite class.

```
this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
```

however is defined inside the callback function for the Image's **onload** event. So my best guess is the time you call the **animate()** method on a Sprite instance the onload event didn't fire yet thus the context isn't defined.

Comment: Thanx!  So the idea is to create a Promise.all loading all images first, before I trigger anything else I guess.

Comment: No problem @Cornelius! In any case I'd move the initialization of this.ctx into the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It appears `step()` is being called before the `ctx` is defined. Most likely because `step()` is called before the `img.onload()` callback which creates the `ctx`.

Make sure to call `step()` after `init()`.

Or setup the `ctx` in the `constructor`, with:

```
this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```